# setting timers mode 2 autoreload 8051

Tags: microcontroller, timer, 8051

I have to create a square wave of 200 micro seconds  By using the auto reload timer I have found  a3h by doing the following calculation 255 - 92 (decimals) = 0xa3  so i set the timer this way : mov th0 ,#0a3h.But the way they solved it is by setting th0 to -92 why are they using a negative value ? could this possibly be the same as my answer ?

Comment: Who is THEY, and you do realize that the binary representation of -92 is A4h?

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes. Timers count till #0FFh at auto reload mode. So by subtracting 92 from 255 you are saying system to count 92 times.

As I understand you want to know the difference between assigning -92 and 0xa3. Nothing. Compiler converts -92 to 0xa3 when creating the .hex file. Assigning -92 is just a simple and user-friendly way.